# WebForms view engine documentation?

Tags: asp.net

I have maybe very very Simple Question:

Where i can find documentation about expressions and syntax of WebForms view engine?

And what is the difference between

```
<%: expression %>
```

and

```
<%= expression %>
```

?

in advance thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%: expression %>` renders the content with HTML encoding, whereas `<%= expression %>` renders it as is.

See Scott Guthrie's post [New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

i ve got it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h(VS.71).aspx